# List comprehension and or spacing with a new-line

Tags: python, pep8

This seems like a really simple question; but I can't see how it's actually possible. I normally fairly good my code being PEP8 compliant. 83 characters is fine type of thing. I've got a longish list (dictionary) comprehension combined with an `or` that I'm trying to take to a new-line but I can't work out how to get the `or` onto the new-line.

A much simplified version is:

```
>>> test = {'a' : None, 'b' : None}
>>> b = ','.join([k for k in test
...               if test[k]]) or 'hello'
```

Whenever ( wherever ) I try to put the `or 'hello'` on a new-line it fails miserably; the command line interpreter and emacs' parser don't understand either so it may not be possible.

Is it possible to put `or 'hello'` on a new line and if so where would it go?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of:
[Stack Overflow - How can I make my Python code stay under 80 characters a line][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070684/how-can-i-make-my-python-code-stay-under-80-characters-a-line

Comment: "Apparently I've forgotten all python syntax".   Please bookmark the following link. http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#line-structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose in parentheses. This will work.

```
>>> test = {'a' : None, 'b' : None}
>>> b = (','.join([k for k in test if test[k]])
...      or 'hello')
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to match the actual problem of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If a line becomes too long, split it into several statements to enhance readability:

```
b = ','.join(k for k in test if test[k])
if not b:
    b = 'hello'
```

(I also changed the list comprehension to a more appropriate generator expression.)

Comment: I'd love to put it in a new statement but I'm joining this onto another value, which I'd rather not do twice as it'd decrease readability; but that you for the generator tip.

Answer (score 2):

You mark the line continuation explicitly with a backslash:

```
>>> test = {'a' : None, 'b' : None}
>>> b = ','.join([k for k in test if test[k]]) \
...          or 'hello'
```