# How to choose proper variable names for long names in python

Tags: python, pep8

I need help choosing proper names for variables with long actual names. I have read pep8 docs, but I couln't find addressed such issue.

Would you rename `very_long_variable_name` to something like `vry_lng_var_nm` or would you leave it as it is. I notice that pythons build in libraries have very short names and I'd like to follow the conventions if it exists for this case.

I know I can name it something not very descriptive and add description, which would explain its meaning, but what do you think should be the variables name.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19984877/

Comment: The guy wrote his life's story as a function name. Do you think it is related to my question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PEP8 for long method's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984877/pep8-for-long-methods-name)

Comment: It's an opinionated question else the dupe is perfect. There's no right or wrong way, since even the PEP does not address this in particular (doesn't feel the need to).

Comment: `import this` -> readability counts. A lot.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## TLDR

There is no absolute necessity for short names, what is important is clarity. A good rule of thumb is to use different means to provide different level of details about your program:

- Variable names should describe *what* things are.
- Your code itself already describes *how* things are done.
- Comments and docstrings should describe *why* things are done this
  way.

In the end, obeying these rules will oftentimes help you choose concise variable names by removing the superfluous information they contain.

## Long answer

PEP8 does not necessarily recommend short names. It does so only for [modules](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) and [type variable names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#type-variable-names). What is important is for names to be clear and to use a consistent convention across a module.

I usually avoid abbreviations, except for well-known ones. Hence, `very_long_variable_name` is better than `vry_lng_var_nm`. You should use short names if it helps readability, not for the sake of having short names.

Yet, that does not answer the question of *what makes a name clear*. There is no unique answer to that, but here are a few advices that may help.

### Names should reflect usage not implementation

[This one is actually part of PEP8.](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#overriding-principle)

The name of a variable, in particular function names, should  describe *what* it does and not *how* it does it. It is already the role of the code you write to describe *how* things are done. For instance, the built-in function `sorted` is not called `timsort` (which is the algorithm CPython uses for sorting).

Similarly, if you have a list of numbers stored in a variable, you should describe *what* this list of numbers represents. Say it is a list of students' grades, you could then call it `student_grades`, but not `list_of_numbers`.

If you have multiple variables which represent the same *kind of things*, you can qualitatively describe what each variable contains.

```
good_students = filter(lambda s: s.grade >= 90, students)
average_students = filter(lambda s: 60 <= s.grade < 90, students)
bad_students = filter(lambda s: s.grade < 60, students)
```

Notice how I described students *qualitatively* with `good`, `average` and `bad` instead of *quantitatively* with names such as `students_with_grades_above_90`. This describes *what* the categories of students are without going into the details of *how* we build each category.

Remember that the people reading your code are programmers. If they need to know *how* things are done, they will read your code. Your variables provide a higher level of abstraction that describes what is happening without necessarily describing how.

### Put details in comments and docstrings

Variable names are at a very high level of abstraction. The code you write describes *how* things are done at a low level of abstraction. Use comments and doc strings for everything that falls in between, such as higher-level explanations of *how* things are done and *why* things are done that way.

Adding documentation in comments and doc strings fills the gap between the level of detail given by names and that given by the code. If you feel it is important that the reader knows *how* and *why* things are done, then this information should go in comments.

In this example, a variable was given a long and very specific name: `students_with_grades_above_90`. We may feel the need for a very specific name because the function is undocumented.

```
def get_good_students(students):
    return filter(lambda s: s.grade > 90, students)

students_with_grades_above_90 = get_good_students(students)
```

By adding some documentation, we can relax how specific that name is. Making it both shorter and more abstract. If the reader is not sure about what `get_good_students` returns, they should look at the function's docstring.

```
def get_good_students(students):
    """Return students with grade above 90"""
    return filter(lambda s: s.grade > 90, students)

good_students = get_good_students(students)
```

### Too specific name might mean too specific code

If you feel you need a very specific name for a function, it might be that the function is too specific itself.

```
# Very long name because very specific behaviour
def get_students_with_grade_above_90(students):
    return filter(lambda s: s.grade > 90, students)

# Adding a level of abstraction shortens our method name here
def get_students_above(grade, students):
    return filter(lambda s: s.grade > grade, students)

# What we mean here is very clear and the code is reusable
good_students = get_students_above(90, students)
```

Also notice how  using `grade` as a parameter allowed to remove it from the function's name without loss of clarity.

### Keep short scopes for quick lookup

Encapsulate logic in shorter scopes. This way, you don't need to give as much detail with variable names, as it can be looked up quickly a few lines above. A rule of thumb is to make your functions fit in your IDE without scrolling. Encapsulate some logic in a new function if you go beyond that.

```
# line 6
names = ['John', 'Jane']

... # Hundreds of lines of code

# line 371
# Wait what was names again?
if 'Kath' in names:
    ...
```

Here I lost track of what `names` was and scrolling up will make me lose track of even more. This is better:

```
# line 6
names = ['John', 'Jane']

# I encapsulate part of the logic in another function to keep scope short
x = some_function()
y = maybe_a_second_function(x)

# line 13
# Sure I can lookup names, it is right above
if 'Kath' in names:
    ...
```

### Spend time thinking about readability

The last but not least is to devote time thinking about how you can make your code more readable. Remember that code is not only read by computers, it is read by programmers too! The best code is the code that everyone can read, and thus everyone can improve.