# What is the use-case for a nested function pattern in Python?

Tags: python, lambda, inner-classes, pep8

While there is a lot of discussion around construction and use of nested functions, there is very little info on *when* to use them. What I'm trying to find out is: when is it idiomatic to use a nested function? When should you use `lambda x: <function>` over a nested function?

Python is a language that lets you do a lot of things you *shouldn't* (ie: using globals). Is this a feature that, while you can use it, you should not?

A scenario I envisioned for using one is in unit testing. Let's say you a method defined like this:

```py
def FunctionOne(varone: int, vartwo: object) -> None:
  assert varone == vartwo()
```

vartwo is a function that is passed into the function. Now we want to unittest this. So we write a (partial) unit test that looks like this:

```py
def unittest() -> None:
  def test_function() -> int:
    return 1
  FuncitonOne(1, test_function)
```

The specifics here are:

1. The function is only needed in the scope of the unit test function.
2. The function is never called elsewhere.

Therefore, to summarize: when should you (if ever) use a nested function with Python?

Comment: a lot of ink on the web have been dedicated to this topic. this is a here's a good read: https://realpython.com/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for this link, it looks like my terminology of "nested functions" might have been a tripping point when researching.

Comment: The real question is *when should you use a `lambda`*? Pretty much, the only time you should use `lambda` is for any *anonymous function*. And really, that is mostly a matter of *style*. There is nothing that a lambda gives you that isn't available witha  full function definition, and there's things that a full function definition can do that lambda cannot. Note, Guido actually wanted to *remove* lambda in the transition from Python 2 to 3.

Comment: Now, the only time you should nest a function is if you need to create *a new function* on each invocation of the outer function. This is often the case for higher order functions that return functions, or a function taht takes advantage of a closure created by the nested function.

Comment: I think the important part to understand is that "nested functions" is really just a case of creating an object inside a function... functions *are just objects*. And you can think of `def foo(...): ...` as syntactic sugar to a call to the `function` class constructor, so `foo = function(...)` This is actually possible, although, you almost never need to invoke the actual function constructor, and it isn't user friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, notice that a nested function offers features that a `lambda` or a global function do not have.

- It can be multi-statements, by opposition to a `lambda`
- It can have a closure, by opposition to a global function

Thus, a purely feature-oriented answer would be to use a nested function whenever you need to define a multi-statements function with a closure.

Here is an example of such a function.

```
def create_counter(step):
    start = 0
    def count():
        print(start)
        start += step
    return count
```

Note that another recurring example of that use-case are decorators.

```
def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        ...
        f(*args)
        ...
    return wrapper

@decorator
def my_function(*args):
    ...
```

Another reason you might want to use a nested function is to make it *private* in some sense, since the function will then be local and cannot be accessed globally. Although, I see very few cases where this is useful since by [choosing proper function names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48721582/5079316), it should not bother you to have helper functions in your namespace.